# Which method of hotspotting consumes the least power from the connected device?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, battery, power-management, tethering

When a MacBook Pro is connected to an iPhone's hotspot through USB-C to lightning, the MacBook Pro will automatically charge the iPhone. This consumes additional power from the MacBook Pro's battery. I presume (but do not know for sure) that it consumes the MacBook Pro's battery at a higher rate if the iPhone is on <100% battery than if it is already at 100% battery.

In situations where we want to conserve the MacBook Pro's battery as long as possible, which method of hotspotting (i.e. wired vs wireless) drains the MacBook Pro battery least?

What I'm really trying to learn is if you're without an external power source, and using a MacBook on a hotspot of an iPhone, which preserves the MacBook Pro's battery longer - wired or wireless, and does the answer depend at all on whether the iPhone is fully charged?

Comment: Make sure the phone is fully charged first??

Comment: @SolarMike I added another paragraph to make it clearer

Comment: I think wireless would last longer if your iPhone is not fully charged (I guess below 90%?) because newer iPhones support fast charge which draws a lot of power.